# tsql-Joining tables with group by

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Have 2 tables TableA

```
    StudentID   MeetingID  TeacherID   Date
     001         1002581    1056      10-12-2012
     001         1006789    1056      10-13-2012
     001         1006754    1058      10-13-1012
```

Have one more table B

```
     StudentID      MeetingID    TeacherID     Date        Value
         001          1002581      1056         10-12-201     15
         001          1002856      1056         10-20-2012    21
```

The conditions are max(date) of a particular student teacher meeting from table A matches the max(date) of the same student teacher meeting in table B with the value. I would like to see the resultset as something like

```
   StudentID       MeetingID     TeacherID     Date          Value
   001             1006789       1056          10-20-2012     21
```

How can i achieve the above resultset

Comment: Uhm, no really sure on the resultset you give here. You said you want a max(date) on tablea student-meeting-teacher matching the max(date) on tableb student-meeting-teacher. When i look at your result, that should be not the value 21 record, but the value 15 record....

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm curious why you have the same data in two separate tables instead of linking them via ID. I.e. Meetings -> Values

Per your requirements, this should work.  This finds the most recent meeting which is present in *both* tables.

```
SELECT B.* 
FROM B INNER JOIN A ON B.StudentID = A.StudentID AND B.MeetingID = A.MeetingID AND B.Date = A.Date
WHERE B.Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM A WHERE A.StudentID = B.StudentID AND A.MeetingID = B.MeetingID)
```

Here's the Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d15ca/4

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 c.StudentID,c.MeetingID,c.TeacherID,c.tab1_dates,c.VALUE
FROM 
(
    SELECT a.StudentID,a.MeetingID,a.TeacherID,a.Dates AS tab1_dates,b.Dates AS tab2_dates,b.VALUE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.Dates,b.Dates) AS RN1
    FROM tab2 b
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT StudentID,MeetingID,TeacherID,Dates FROM tab1
    ) a
    ON b.StudentID = a.StudentID
    AND b.TeacherID = a.TeacherID
        ) c
ORDER BY RN1 DESC
```

--SQL Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c6cea/1

Sorry, couldn't format well.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for formatting. Can you tell how to format the code after pasting ?

Comment: what if i have multiple students? it is still returning one row